# Show and hide, enable and disable depending on radios and checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Ok I am rephrasing my questions into two smaller modules:

1) When we click on the radio button with name electronics in the form, the div with id 'electronics which was originally hidden should be shown. My jquery function for this is incorrect. Any pointers ?

2) The textbox to enter quantities in the div id electronics should be initially disabled and then become active when the user clicks the checkbox next to the item name.FOr example:Radio

My code below:

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
            <style>
                div{display:none}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
             <input type="radio" name="household" id   ="electronics" value="electronics">Electronics<br>
             <input type="radio" name="household" id="cookware" value="cookware">Cookware<br>
              <input type="radio" name="household" id="both"  value="both">Both<br>
            </form>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(input[type="radio"]).click(function(){
                        $("div").show;
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <div id="electronics">
                <input type="checkbox" value="radio" name="radio">Radio &nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text1"><br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="phone" name="phone">Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text2"><br>
</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use show() instead of show.

Comment: You're right! Edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

1. Give the div a class and remove the ID from the radios since ID must be unique
2. Fix the type of the input textbox to type=text.
3. add the click event to the checkboxes
4. run the test of the checkboxes onload to disable/enable the text fields

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on("click",function () {
    $(".selections").hide(); // hide them all
    if (this.value=="both") $(".selections").show(); // show both
    else $("#"+this.value).show(); // show the one with ID=radio value
  });
  $('.selections input[type="checkbox"]').on("click",function() {
//    $(this).next().prop("disabled",!this.checked); // disable if not checked
    $(this).next().toggle(this.checked); // hide if not checked
  });
  $('.selections input[type="text"]').each(function() { // initialise
//      $(this).prop("disabled",!$(this).prev().is(":checked")); 
        $(this).toggle($(this).prev().is(":checked")); 
  });
});
```

```css
.selections { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="household" value="electronics">Electronics
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="household" value="cookware">Cookware
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="household" value="both">Both
    <br>
</form>
<div id="electronics" class="selections">
    <input type="checkbox" value="radio" name="radio">Radio &nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="phone" name="phone">Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: mplungjan, I am a little confused on your reference to "this" in jquery. Please see your first code snippet in solution.

Comment: It is the DOM acces instead you can use $(this).val() if you want to stick with jQuery. I often use `this` for value and id - mostly for ID since that is `$(this).attr("id")` or `.prop("id")` which is more typing

Answer (score 0):

The selector is wrong

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                    $("div").show();
                });
            });
```

or

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(":radio").click(function(){
                    $("div").show();
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you selector is wrong and show function supposed to be `.show()`. Put this js code in script section.

**Answer for Question 1 and 2**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* question 1 */
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            $("div").show();
   });

    /* question 2 */
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function(){            

     if($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
        $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
     }
     else
     {
        $(this).next().attr('disabled','disabled');
     }

   })
});
```

**Here is the markup. I change a little bit(hide the div and disabled input text at initial start**.

```
<body>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="household" id   ="electronics" value="electronics">Electronics<br>
      <input type="radio" name="household" id="cookware" value="cookware">Cookware<br>
      <input type="radio" name="household" id="both"  value="both">Both<br>
    </form>

    <div id="electronics" style="display:none">
        <input type="checkbox" value="radio" name="radio">Radio &nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text1" disabled><br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="phone" name="phone">Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="textbox" name="text2" disabled><br>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a class on the radio button just in case you add more radio buttons in the page...

```
<input type="radio" name="household" class="myradio" value="electronics">Electronics<br>
<input type="radio" name="household" class="myradio"  value="cookware">Cookware<br>
<input type="radio" name="household" class="myradio"   value="both">Both<br>
```

Also on checkboxes...

```
<div id="electronics" style="display:none">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" value="radio" name="radio">Radio &nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="text_radio" name="text_radio"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" value="phone" name="phone">Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="text_phone" name="text_phone"><br>
</div>
```

Then disable checkboxes as soon as the page loads and create the click function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // disable all text inputs
    $(".textbox").prop("disabled", true);

    $(".myradio").click(function(){
        //get value from this radio and show respective div
        $("#"+$(this).val()).show();
        //enable text input from #text_(value)
        $("#text_"+$(this).val()).prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

Comment: `disabled` is technically a property as oppose to an attribute. Use `.prop('disabled', true);` instead. See [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) as a reference...