# if radio button is checked, display divs and textbox

Tags: php, jquery

Reposting this question. I need to approach it from a different way than
[Show and hide, enable and disable depending on radios and checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145562/show-and-hide-enable-and-disable-depending-on-radios-and-checkboxes)

My old way below:

1. First I am not supposed to use the click function for radio buttons. I need to check if radio buttons are checked and then display the electronics div or cookware-items div accordingly. Also need to display both if the radio button option "both" is checked.
2. The textbox fields in electronics div and cookware items div for the user to input quantities should be  displayed only when the checkbox for the respective electronics or cookware item is checked.

Any inputs ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <style>
            div{display:none}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
         <input type="radio" name="household" id   ="electronics" value="electronics">Electronics<br>
         <input type="radio" name="household" id="cookware" value="cookware">Cookware<br>
          <input type="radio" name="household" id="both"  value="both">Both<br>
        </form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(input[type="radio"]).click(function(){
                    $("#electronics").show;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="electronics">
            <input type="checkbox" value="radio" name="radio">Radio &nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text1"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="phone" name="phone">Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text2"><br>

        <div id="cookware-items">
            <input type="checkbox" value="grinder" name="grinder">Grinder&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text1"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="mixer" name="mixer">Mixer&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text2"><br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('input[type="radio"]')`, Also in HTML IDs must be unique

Comment: Why are you "not supposed to use click?"

Comment: the instructor feels that there is a easier way to do it by checking if the radio buttons are checked and displaying accordingly. I just dont know how to do it !

Comment: I believe I already [answered this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145562/show-and-hide-enable-and-disable-depending-on-radios-and-checkboxes/29145840?noredirect=1#comment46538817_29145840). Please next time let us know when it is homework and do not open a new identical question. See original answer for hiding instead of disabling

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/87wtw172/1/

Comment: why can't you use the click event for radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit checkbox Cookware's value to cookware-items

Using jquery hide and show like this:

Live demo: http://code.freetuts.net/editor.html?id=241

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <style>
            div{display:none}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="household" value="electronics">Electronics<br>
            <input type="radio" name="household" value="cookware-items">Cookware<br>
            <input type="radio" name="household" value="both">Both<br>
        </form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('input[name="household"]').click(function() 
                {
                    // Hide 2 divs
                    $('#electronics').hide();
                    $('#cookware-items').hide();

                    // Show by current checkbox
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if (value == 'both'){
                        $('#electronics').show();
                        $('#cookware-items').show();
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#'+value).show();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="electronics">
            <input type="checkbox" value="radio" name="radio">Radio &nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text1"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="phone" name="phone">Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text2"><br>
        </div>
        <div id="cookware-items">
            <input type="checkbox" value="grinder" name="grinder">Grinder&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text1"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="mixer" name="mixer">Mixer&nbsp;&nbsp;2000&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="text2"><br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: user2963055 the else option for your function defined is not working. The if condition for showing both values is working. Any pointers ?

Comment: View demo here: http://code.freetuts.net/editor.html?id=241

I've edited some of the information in your HTML so you have to copy all code

Comment: thankyou. I have also understood the code now and its working. Do you also know how to add the textboxes shown inside the div only when the checkbox next to the item selected is clicked ?

Comment: Like this?  http://code.freetuts.net/editor.html?id=242

Comment: No http://stackoverflow.com/users/2963055/thehalfheart. I have done the code below but I need it edited to add every textbox whenever the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Demo: http://code.freetuts.net/editor.html?id=242 Exactly?